# Does bitcoin have transaction fees?

Tags: transaction-fees

Does bitcoin have transaction fees when sending money from on wallet to another ? How much % is the fee ?

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/43154/5406

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Bitcoin transactions have transaction fee. It is not proportional to amount of Bitcoins sent, but it is proportional to the size of transaction and it is measured in satoshi/byte. (10^8 Satoshi is 1 Bitcoin)

The fees changes from time to time because of market conditions. You can find a good idea of what fees to pay on this site https://bitcoinfees.21.co/.

Comment: 1 or 2$ fees is a bit misleading. In the community we speak about fees in Satoshi per byte. When mempool is down (as currently), you can create transactions with 10Satoshi/byte. See current status also here: https://bitcoinfees.21.co/, which tells you how much Satoshi/Byte you need, to get your transaction through the next block(s).

Comment: Nice link. I will removed the 1-2$ reference with the link. I specifically mentioned market conditions to highlight that tx fee changes.